# Установка SASS на Mac OS Big sure

Tags: macos, sass, arm

Подскажите как установить компилятор Sass на MacBook на M1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала проверим если у нас ruby

```
ruby -v
```

Если не установлена, установим с помощью homebrew

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" 
brew install ruby
```

После того как мы имеем ruby можно ставить sass

```
sudo gem install sass
```

Comment: Ruby Sass является устаревшим и не поддерживается с 2019 года. Вместо него следует использовать Dart Sass

Comment: А запускать gem через sudo вообще жутко вредный совет

Comment: @andreymal отлично предлагайте свою альтернативу

Comment: Я уже предложил Dart Sass, через Homebrew отлично ставится https://github.com/sass/dart-sass#from-homebrew-os-x